# What is the best way to locally store and quickest way to retrieve app user settings/preferences?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.

In my Xamarin Forms app I only want to notify the user with a push notification if a condition is met(even if the app is in the background). The condition is chosen by user when the user registers.

At the moment I store that choice locally on the phone, using SQL Lite.

In my app the speed to which I notify the user is crucial. On Notification Received I have to check against that condition, so I pull the user's choice out of the local database to see whether to notifiy them or not, but that can cost seconds.

Is there a faster way to retrieve that choice/condition, an alternative faster way than just storing it in a local db file? 
These preferences have to be available app wide, in the PCL as well as Android and iOS projects.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by your guys' answers, I researched and ended up using **Xamarin Essentials NuGet package** by Microsoft. Its currently a pre-release and you can only see it if you check the pre-release option in NuGet Packages for solution.

Seems very easy to use and so far preferences are available in PCL and android. I have not tried the iOS yet. Here is the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms

All you do then to store the key value pairs is:

```
private void SaveUserPreferences (string value1, string value2, string value3)
        {
            Preferences.Set("Key1",value1);
            Preferences.Set("Key2",value2);
            Preferences.Set("Key3",value3);
            ...............................
        }
```

In order to retrieve them in a class after adding "using Xamarin.Essentials"
(for example in your Android project)

```
var preferenceValue = Preferences.Get("key", "defaultValueIfNotExists");
```

In order to install for Android make sure you add this in all Activity classes.
For example in MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) 
{
    //...
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle); // add this line to your code
}
```

Nothing needs to be done for iOS.

Also make sure you install it in all projects.

Hope it helps other people too.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't need any data structure the faster and easiest method for that kind of thing is `Shared preferences`.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Forms has a built-in [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms) Dictionary you can use for storing simple types

```
bool myKey;

// retrieve value
if (Application.Current.Properties.Exists("mykey")) {
  myKey = (bool)Application.Current.Properties["mykey"];
}

//set value if it already exists in Dictionary
Application.Current.Properites["mykey"] = myKey;
// or add it if it doesn't
Application.Current.Properties.Add("mykey",myKey);

// properties will auto-save, but you can force save with
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SharedPreferences as mentioned by @MichaelMontero . You need to implement it to your Android/iOS/UWP. Then make use of dependency service to retrieve it to your shared/pcl/netstandard code.

Simple implementation of it via Android:

```
void SetValue(string key, string value)
{
    var settings = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("PreferenceName", FileCreationMode.Private);
    var holder = settings.Edit();

    holder.PutString(key, value);
}

string GetValue(string key)
{
     var settings = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("PreferenceName", FileCreationMode.Private);
     return settings.GetString(key, string.Empty);
}
```

You can research for the implementation of it to iOS/UWP also since they have different kind of implementation.